# datagridview alternatingrow alignment

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my project I read a csv file and store it in a DataTable and then display it in a DataGridView. But I want a column that the values are aligned to the right that is in column 2 so I write:

```
grigliavenduto.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = 
                                 DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

But this happens to one row but not the next, a sort of yes no yes no yes no .... so how can I by code to set the alignment to the right of the column AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle 2? thanks

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you will be able to specify an alternate style for a specific column, instead can you try the **CellFormatting** event

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == [your index])
    {
      //conditions and then set like e,RowIndex % 2 == 0
                e.CellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the property: `grigliavenduto.Columns[2].AlternatingCellStyle` to the same as above, this would probably work.

But I think there should be a property which affects both normal and alternating rows, look at the properties of the DataGridView and play around a bit.

Comment: it doesn't work for AlternatingCellStyle and i don't find the property